# Change Top/down page shortcut

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, high-sierra, shortcut

I can't find any way to change (or cancel) the annoying shortcut "cmd+ arrow up/down" which jumps to top of the file each time i accidentally press the up/down arrows instead of right/left, for developers this shortcut is super annoying!

please help :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try using fn + ↑/↓ key combination to scroll one page at a time.

Comment: I want to cancel this specific scrolling shortcut... not looking for alternatives